# В рассылке telegram-бот python не может отправить прикрепленное фото

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Сделал рассылку по idшникам из файлика, если вставить вместо `img = open(imageFile, 'rb') bot.send_photo(chatID, img)` вот это`bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])` то по команде /special "Вводимый текст" он сделает рассылку с надписью что ты ему отправил. Но с прикреплением фотки такое не канает, кто знает в чем может быть причина?

```
import telebot


joinedFile = open('C:\\Users\\Quillish Wammy\\Desktop\\botuser.txt', 'r')
joinedUsers = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()


bot = telebot.TeleBot("")




@bot.message_handler(commands=['special'])
def mess(message):
    for user in joinedUsers:
        img = open(imageFile, 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(user, img, caption='TEST')




@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'go'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет")
    f = open("C:\\Users\\Quillish Wammy\\Desktop\\Документ Microsoft Word.docx", "rb")
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f)
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open('C:\\Users\\Quillish Wammy\\Desktop\\botuser.txt', 'a')
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Введи /help для просмотра команд")



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# С помощью шага
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def some(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите подпись к фото')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, some_1)


def some_1(message):
    with open('./files/menu/bar.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f, caption=message.text)


# С помощью аргумента к команде
@bot.message_handler(commands=['some'])
def some_2(message):
    with open('./files/menu/bar.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, f, caption=message.text.split()[1])
```